# Angular Service created function needs this keyword

Tags: javascript, angularjs

While the question is more I suppose javascript type question more so than an Angular question,  I was creating a service in which I would call it like this

```
// controller injects activityApi , then service function call is made
var activities = activityApi.getActivityById(1122);
```

I get an error if I do not put "this" keyword in front of function name
1. Why do I need "this."
2. What other alternatives?  ( I am trying to get into the habit of not doing old school javascript with  `function blah() { ... }`

```
this.getActivityById = function(id) {
        $http.get('/Umbraco/Api/ActivityApi/GetActivity').
            success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log(data);
            return data;
            }).
       error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
           // log error
       });
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are writing a factory make use of an object inside the factory ,and put all your calls into it.like

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .factory('activityApi', activityApi);

    activityApi.$inject = ['$http'];

    function activityApi($http) {
        var service = {
              getActivityById : getActivityById ,
        };
        return service;


     function getActivityById (id) {
        $http.get('/Umbraco/Api/ActivityApi/GetActivity').
          success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
           console.log(data);
           return data;
        }).
       error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
          // log error
       });
    };

    };
})();
```

here you are returning factory object in which calling function is available.

Here you can call the factory function as

```
var activities = activityApi.getActivityById(1122);
```

Comment: I reading about both factories and services , while I "might" instead switch to using a factory , I'm wondering about the  `angular.module('app').factory..` syntax   is that "better" or preferred over mine in which I do  `app.service("activityApi", function ($http) { ... });` ?

Comment: I would prefer `angular.module('app').factory..`, because it is not a good approach to assign the complete application to single variable app and using it globally.

Comment: @NikhilVM, whatever you return from `factory` becomes global as well. In this sense it's not different from service.

Comment: @Maximus, you are right, but rather than assigning complete app to a variable , we can call the app instance by `angular.module('app')`.

Comment: @NikhilVM, sorry, can't understand how it's relevant to `service vs factory` question. Can you clarify?

Comment: I did specifically have in title of question `service`  but I do like factory

Comment: when we use factory, we just create an object, adding properties to it, then return that same object.When we pass this factory into controller, those properties on the object will now be available in that controller.If using an object, we can use the factory provider.

when we use Service , we just instantiated with the ‘new’ keyword and you’ll add properties to ‘this’ and the service will return ‘this’.When we pass the service into controller, those properties on ‘this’ will now be available on that controller.service is better if using with class

Comment: @NikhilVM   - I'm getting error with doing your factory     `angular.js:13642 Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.6/$injector/unpr?p0=activityFactoryApiProvider%20%3C-%20activityFactoryApi%20%3C-NaNetailController`

Comment: @JeremyMiller, you need to inject `activityApi` factory to your controller.

Comment: Why can't I do the angular.module('app'  above?   I CAN do it this way -->   `app.factory("activityFactoryApi", ['$http', activityFactoryApi]);`

Comment: you can do like 

`angular.module('app')
.factory('activityFactoryApi',['$http', activityFactoryApi]);

Comment: added the new factory.js file to index.html?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding angular's services and factories. Both `.service` and `.factory` return functions. However, angular's `$injector` calls the function returned by `.service` with `new` keyword (using `$instantiate` method), whereas it calls `.factory` function as is using `invoke` method. Since it uses `new` keyword for service functions, you have to have `this` keyword inside your function to reference the object, created by `new` and returned from the function.

As @NikhilVM shows, you can use `factory` instead of `service` if you want to avoid using this. Both service and `factory` return values are cached, so if the factory returns an object it becomes global. So in this sense it's no different from `service` using `this` to add methods. Using `factory` has the advantage in that you can return a function constructor to be later called to instantiate multiple class instances, while you can't do that with `.service`.